# Sqlite debug on device and see databases and tables

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

How to see the `SQLite` Database file in eclipse while debugging Application on Device?

Comment: create your sqlite db on sd card, or execute your application in Emulator.

Comment: you can install the app on emulator

Comment: You can't see the database on eclipse, but you can use *adt* to copy the database to your computer, and use any SQLite browser.

Comment: for see databse file..,you sholud use squlite browser.

Answer (score 1):

In device it's not possible, but any way you can achieve it by running your application on emulator

For achieving this on emulator First Run your application on respective emulator, and than follow these steps to get `.SQLite` Database

```
Window->Show View->File Explorer->n this view go to data/data/"your app name"/databases/"your database"
```

And export that database file to your local machine and view it on some addons like best one for me is [Fire Fox  SQLite Manager 0.8.1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/?src=)

Answer (score 1):

First attach your device from system then try

adb pull /data/data/yourpackagename/databases/databasename.db

**your package name will be like com.example.androidapp**

It will pull database file in current directory. now try

sqlite3 databasename.db

use sqlite commands to view tables, like select * from tablename etc;

Answer (score 0):

If that's possible then anyone can see/snatch database of any application. So my answer is viewing database while testing on real android device is not possible.

Yes you can view/get database in your data/data directory if you are testing on emulator.

One more thing, you could get database by giving a SD-card location instead of internal storage path and then you can use any SQLite browser tool to view/check data stored inside it.